# Interactive 3D House Interior in Blender

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

I would like to ask if is it possible to make an interactive 3d house interior in blender or will I need another program to pair with blender? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Blender < 2.7x you could do it with Game Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Its genuine to ask such type of question, because every one has the doubt on any free thing/software that if it has a capability to do complex work or not.

> I would like to ask if is it possible to make an interactive 3d house
>   interior in blender or will I need another program to pair with
>   blender?

No, you don't need any other software to make an Interactive 3D House. Blender has the capability to do it alone. It has some awesome add-ons made by some expert programmers which will help you in making it.
You will be inspired if you watch this small [**clip**](https://youtu.be/mN0zPOpADL4) made by [**Blender Studios**](https://blender.studio/) in **Blender** itself. The perfection is outstanding, you will be thankful to have **Blender**.